# API causing multiple JSON arrays in file

Tags: python, json, pandas, csv

I am writing an API that needs to be able to call a list of URLs from a file and run the URLs through the code. Which I have working. The only down side is now I have a single JSON file with multiple JSON arrays in it and can not get it to convert to a CSV. Any help greatly appreciated.

```
import requests
import json
import pandas as pd
import csv
from pathlib import Path

Path("/test2/test2").mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)

links = pd.read_csv('file.csv')
test = []
for url in links:
    response = requests.get(url, headers={'CERT': 'cert'}).json()
    test.append(response[:])
    json2 = json.dumps(test)
    f = open('/test2/test2/data.json','a')
    f.write(json2)
    f.close()
    
    
df = pd.read_json('/test2/test2/data.json', lines=True)
df.to_csv('/test2/test2/data.csv')

df = pd.read_csv('/test2/test2/data.csv')
test = df['ID']
test2 = df['Code']
test3 = df['Name']
header=['ID', 'Code', 'Name']
df.to_csv('/test2/test2/test.csv', columns =  header)
```

Ive tried to include coding such as `json3 = json2.replace('}][{', '}, {')` as well as trying to

```
testList = []
with open('/test2/test2/data.json') as f:
    for jsonObj in f:
        testDict = json.loads(jsonObj)
        testList.append(testDict)
```

And have had no luck. With this I got past the I mean technically I can open the file in notepad and change `}][{` to `}, {` but I would like to do it programmatically as this would be an automated API. Any help greatly appreciated.

EDIT:
Sample Output:

```
[{"ID": 5, "OldID": 1, "Code": 5, "Name": "Jeff"}][{"ID": 2, "OldID": 4, "Code": 0, "Name": "James"}]
```

Thats a scrubbed down version. The ouput is going into one line, which works fine running the code with just one URL, but with two URLs it gives the issue. For some reason I can not get replace to correct the `']['`. Running one URL having it as a list/array `[]` doesn't bother the conversion its just the start of the new list/array that does.

Comment: Why can't you just write the data as a CSV file in the first place?

Comment: Each JSON object should be written to a different line if using `lines=True`, but "change `}][{`" indicates it is all on one line.  If you're having trouble reading the data, actually providing a sample of the data along with the code that fails would help us reproduce your issue and suggest a solution.

Comment: @JohnGordon I tried to write the data straight to CSV skipping the part where I put it to a JSON file, but didn't have any luck with finding a way to take the data from the request and push directly to CSV without having to create the JSON file. Do you know a method that might allow for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never could get this to not combine JSON arrays in the file, but I was able to sort those arrays into one JSON object so that I could convert and parse the file. Here was the code that did it's magic and completed my process.

```
with fileinput.FileInput('data.json', inplace=True, backup='.bak') as file:
    for line in file:
        print(line.replace('][', ', '), end='')
```

When I added this in between my first JSON write and my pandas call to read the file it was able to find the troublemaking  characters and remove it.